# How to organize architecture of displaying two different Fragments in activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout, android-architecture-components, android-architecture

[image]

I have some sort of architecture issue:

I have Activity in which I need to show one of 3 views (one view at one moment in time):
 1. One view with stable `AppBarLayout` + another part of the screen is
    `NestedScrollView` that needs to be in separate `fragment`.
 2. One view with stable `AppBarLayout` + another part of screen need to be a `fragment` with two tabs to switch between them.
 3. Connection lost view - is a fullscreen view without `AppBar` - just to show that there is no connection.

The upper part of `AppBarLayout` - I made. Looks like good, but I need runtime to switch `Fragments` depending on the response from Server.
I am sending a request to the server in `onCreate` method in `MainActivity`, and then in `onDataLoadedFromServer` callback, depending on response - I am deciding which fragment to create. But my application crashes, because fragments fields are not initialized properly - the view is not attached to fragment. When I am adding fragment in `onCreate` method - everything is working good, but at that time I don't have a response from server.

1. Where to place `TabLayout`? And where `ViewPager`? Do I need to put
   `TabLayout` in `main_activity.xml`, and `ViewPager` in separate
   `fragment_2_layout`. And then add it to `FrameLayout` (container for
   fragment which is located in `main_activity`)?
2. Is it good practice to load some data from the server in the fragment? Or it's better to load data in Activity and then set it through the method
   call to Fragment?

Please, provide some sort of pseudo code to understand logic. Thanks!.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/shop_final_root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.lampa.letyshops.view.activity.ShopFinalActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            <include
                layout="@layout/collapsing_part" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar> 
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_layout_dual_tabs">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <include layout="@layout/shop_final_no_connection_layout" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

```
public MainActivity {

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  loadDataFromServer();
 }

 private void onDataLoaded(Object dto) {
  if (showOneViewLayout) {
   showOneViewLayout();
  } else {
   showTabViewLayout();
  }
 }
}

private void showOneViewLayout() {
 f1 = Fragment1.newInstance(params);
 showFragmentWithoutBackStack(R.id.fragment_holder, f1);
}

private void showTabViewLayout() {
 f2 = Fragment2.newInstance();
 showFragmentWithoutBackStack(R.id.fragment_holder, f2);
}

protected void showFragmentWithoutBackStack(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment) {
 Fragment previousFragment = currentFragment;
 Fragment currentFragment = fragment;
 String fragmentTag = fragment.getClass().getSimpleName();
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
 fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
 if (previousFragment != null) {
  fragmentTransaction.hide(previousFragment);
 }
 fragmentTransaction.add(containerViewId, fragment, fragmentTag)
  .commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```